# Invalid integer:

Tags: apex, trigger

```
Case.ExpMonth__c= Integer.valueof(Account[0].expirationmonth);
```

I am trying to assign value here to `Case.ExpMonth__c`.The `ExpMonth__c` is number data type field.How to typecast the number field?I already tried with decimal and integer.

Comment: What Data Type is `expirationmonth` from `Account`?

Comment: Issue seems to be in `Integer.valueof(Account[0].expirationmonth); ` line. `expirationmonth` field might not be a compatible to Integer typecasting.

Comment: We don't know enough to help you. What context is this in (trigger, Aura, etc)? Is this a compilation error or a runtime error? Please give us more info so we can help. Also, providing any surrounding code would be incredibly useful. We need some more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an educated guess, it appears that you're using a "wrapper class":

```
public class Wrapper {
  @AuraEnabled public String expirationmonth { get; set; }
  // ... //
}
```

Which is then being passed in somehow:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void someMethod(Wrapper[] Account) {
```

And the value happens to be an empty string:

```
System.debug(Account[0].expirationmonth); // empty string '' (not null)
```

Which would be the most likely cause of your error.

The solution is likely to make sure that you have a valid number first:

```
if(Account.size() > 0 && Account[0].expirationmonth?.isNumeric() == true) {
  Case.ExpMonth__c= Integer.valueof(Account[0].expirationmonth); 
}
```

Comment: thanks. It worked as expected.